# Close App from MainActivity only NOT from sub Fragment/Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to close the application on back press.
E.g I've 3 Fragment

1. MainActivity which extends FragmentActivity
2. FragmentTwo which extends Fragment
3. FragmentThree which extends Fragment

So when I on 3rd fragment and back button press go to 2nd fragment. But when I'm on 1st fragment and press back button the app closed with Toast/AlertDialog message.

Comment: please look my naswer below, if you press double to back it finish activity , if you press once it says click again to finish, with toast message

Comment: thanks for your rply. let me try your code

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("")
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {
               Intent i=new Intent(this,xxxx.class);
               startActivity(i);
               dis.super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }).create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please :

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()
{
      if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {          
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this,"click again to finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
            }
        }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Your code working. but i want only a toast message when i'm on 1st fragment.

Comment: when you are coming 1st fragment you want to toast message? before you press backbpress?

Comment: Yes exactly like i want